# What is 'instance=' and 'queryset=' in django?

Tags: django

*what does it do in this function, what does it mean generally?*

```
def createOrder(request, pk):
        OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields = ('product','status'), extra=10)
        customer=Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
        formset=OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none(),instance=customer)
        
        if request.method=='POST':
            
            formset=OrderFormSet(request.POST,instance=customer)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('/')
        context={'formset':formset}
        return render(request, 'accounts/order_form2.html',context)
```

Comment: Firstly, do you know what a formset in Django is?

Comment: I think I do, set of forms generally speaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/models/) creates a formset for model objects that belong to a certain other model object. The first argument is `parent_model` which is the class of the "parent" model (the one to which the others must belong). The second argument is `model` - the model class for which the forms will be created.

With `inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order,...` you are creating a formset that can create forms for `Order`s that belong to a certain `Customer`.

The way you can specify which specific `Customer` all the `Order`s must belong to is by passing the `instance` argument to the formset. An example is given under [Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) in the docs.

The `queryset` argument allows you to limit for which objects in the model to create a form for. In your case, for which `Order`s a form should be displayed. An example is given under [Changing the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) in the docs. By default `queryset` is set to all of the objects in the model, e.g. `Order.objects.all()`.

`Order.objects.none()` selects an [empty queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#none). Setting `queryset` to an empty queryset will mean that no forms will be displayed for existing `Order`s. Only a form for a new `Order` will be displayed.

With `OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none(),instance=customer)` like you have above, you're essentially saying: create a form for a new `Order` object which should be linked to `customer`.